# Objective-C – Core Data entity to hold UILocalNotifications

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uilocalnotification

I want to be able to store a representation of `UILocalNotification`s in Core Data. So for my needs I need to save the fireDate of the UILocalNotification which should be easy as Core Data has support for `NSDate`. I also want to save a repeat interval for the UILocalNotification in the class reference it says that the `repeatInterval` type is `NSCalendarUnit`.

So how would I go about saving the repeatInterval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs `NSCalendarUnit` is a typedef for `NSUInteger`. So in CoreData you would store that as a `Integer 32` type. In your code you can access those properties as `NSNumber`s.

Use `-[NSInteger unsignedIntegerValue]` to get the original `NSUInteger` value.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the documentation, the `NSCalendarUnit` is just a `NSUInteger`, so you could store it as a `NSNumber`, right?